# PKI problems locations in Enterprise PKI mmc

Tags: ssl, certificate, pki, adsi

I did a "renew Cert" on one of my Enterprise subCAs, and it's totally messed up my results on Enterprise PKI in MMC.  In the Certificate Authority snapin, there are now two certs (Certificate #0 and #1). The AIA (ldap) is showing "Unable to Download", with the "original CN=". The CDP (ldap) location has a (1) on it, as does the DeltaCRL. Every time I renew the revocation, it makes both the original cert's crl and a (1). The CDP/DeltaCRL (http) also both show "unable to download", even though the files exist in the directory. The only AIA location that shows OK is the http location.

I need to get rid of the old CA cert (the #0), I'll re-push the new one out via a GPO once this all is resolved.  I tried to remove the AIA via ADSIEdit, and then republish it via "certutil -dspublish" but that gives me a  0x80070057 (WIN32: 87 ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER) error. Trying to connect to the Configuration of the specific CA via ADSIEdit says "server is not operational". In ADSIEdit CN=CDP there are multiple entries, the normal "CA", a "CA-1", and a "CA-1(1)".

This is in our "Test" environment (luckily), but I need to get a proper process sorted out as I need to do this in two other forests.  I'm actually tempted to just totally rebuild a new CA in the other zones instead of fighting with all of this.
All I'm trying to do is re-issue a subCA's cert, and get it to work correctly and report healthy in Enterprise PKI!

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CertSvc\Configuration\OMNI-
TST-CERTAUTH-01-CA-1\CRLPublicationURLs:

CRLPublicationURLs REG_MULTI_SZ =
    0: 65:C:\windows\system32\CertSrv\CertEnroll\%3%8%9.crl
    CSURL_SERVERPUBLISH -- 1
    CSURL_SERVERPUBLISHDELTA -- 40 (64)

```
1: 79:ldap:///CN=%7%8,CN=%2,CN=CDP,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,%6%10
CSURL_SERVERPUBLISH -- 1
CSURL_ADDTOCERTCDP -- 2
CSURL_ADDTOFRESHESTCRL -- 4
CSURL_ADDTOCRLCDP -- 8
CSURL_SERVERPUBLISHDELTA -- 40 (64)

2: 134:http://pki.omni.phish/CertEnroll/%3%4%9.crl
CSURL_ADDTOCERTCDP -- 2
CSURL_ADDTOFRESHESTCRL -- 4
CSURL_ADDTOIDP -- 80 (128)
```

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CertSvc\Configuration\OMNI-
TST-CERTAUTH-01-CA-1\CACertPublicationURLs:

CACertPublicationURLs REG_MULTI_SZ =
    0: 1:C:\Windows\system32\CertSrv\CertEnroll\%1_%3%4.crt
    CSURL_SERVERPUBLISH -- 1

```
1: 3:ldap:///CN=%7,CN=AIA,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,%6%11
CSURL_SERVERPUBLISH -- 1
CSURL_ADDTOCERTCDP -- 2

2: 32:http://%1/ocsp
CSURL_ADDTOCERTOCSP -- 20 (32)

3: 32:http://pki.omni.phish/oscp
CSURL_ADDTOCERTOCSP -- 20 (32)

4: 2:http://pki.omni.phish/CertEnroll/%3.crt
CSURL_ADDTOCERTCDP -- 2
```

Comment: Add the result of `certutil -getreg CA\CRLPublicationURLs` and `certutil -getreg CA\CACertPublicationURLs` to your question.

Comment: Done, replying back so you know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CRLPublicationURLs**

1st, you're publish to the local disk (**C:\Windows\System32\CertSrv\CertEnroll\%3%8%9.crl**) but nowhere else.  Now you may have a manual process in place to upload this CRL to the CDP, in which case this is fine.  Otherwise, you need to add another url (for example **65:file://\\[server]\[share]\%3%8%9.crl**, where [server] is your CDP and [share] is a share for the directory containing your CRLs) so that new CRLs are automatically published to the CDP by the CA.

2nd, you are using a CDP of **http://pki.omni.phish//CertEnroll/%3%4%9.crl**.  The **%4** should be **%8**.

When you renew a CA certificate, you need the original CA certificate and CRL to still be available so that all end-entities that were previously issued certificates still work.  Microsoft CAs do this by appending a **(1)** to the CRL name, just before the .crl extension for the 1st replacement certificate (**Certificate #1** in the MMC) and **(2)** for the next renewal and so on.  This is configured by the **%8** in the **CRLPublicationURLs** registry key.

**CAPublicationURLs**

You are adding the URL to the CA certificate as **http://pki.omni.phish/CertEnroll/%3.crt**. You need to add a **%4** after the **%3**.

The **%4** does a similar job to what **%8** does for CRLs.  Without it, the CA certificate name remains the same.

---

There are three different ways you can fix these:

1. You can use the MMC - under **Extensions** on the CA **Properties** dialog.  However, it's really clumsy to operate.
2. You can use the `certutil -setreg` command, but you have to overwrite all of the settings - you can't edit one line.
3. You can edit the registry directly at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CertSrv\Configuration\[CA Name]`

I find the latter is the simplest.

May I suggest some PKI and Microsoft ADCS revision before you touch production? :-)

Comment: I've gotten most of it out of the "red" now, thanks to your help! The only thing I'm still struggling with is the OSCP part.  I set up the Responder per various how-tos, linked it to the correct OSCP cert, but the location is still showing red...for ALL my CAs, not just this troublesome one.  However, this might be a totally different post LOL

Comment: You seem to have delta CRLs and OCSP running there.  Any specific reason for this?  Maybe you should thoroughly research how to design a Microsoft PKI before you get to grips with the live environment.  If you're not planning to revoke many certificates, you could probably ditch those two.  However, without knowing the ins and outs of your requirements, it would be difficult to commit.
If you do ask another question, maybe Server Fault or Super User would be a better place.  SO is really for programming questions.

Comment: Most of this is because we have to hit the NIST 800-171 requirements.  In NIST's 800-52 rel2 draft 2, it says that OCSP is required but CRL is optional. The previous admin had only implemented CRL / dCRL, and I've yet to get the OCSP to function properly, so until that is done I'm leaving the CRL in place.